# Accordian header images in AngularUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So im currently porting my project from jQuery to AngularJS, I have the following code in jQuery

**jQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var icons = {
      header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
      activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
    };

    $( "#Session" ).accordion({
      icons: icons
    });
});
```

I dont find any icons option in AngularUI. Is there any workaround to add header images in AngularUI accordion? Tried to used font awesome for icons

```
<accordion-group heading="My Current Sessions" class="icon-book">
      <div>Content Goes here</div>
</accordion-group>
```

The above code has icon and heading on adjacent lines, and not on same line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using the accordion directive from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and want to have custom HTML in your accordion heading you can use the `<accordion-heading>` element inside the `<accordion-group>` (instead of relaying on the `heading` attribute).

Here is an example:

```
<accordion>
    <accordion-group>
      <accordion-heading>
        Put any HTML <strong>here</strong><i class="icon-book"></i>
      </accordion-heading>
      This content is straight in the template.
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
```

And the working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/E4QtpTYpHkMmcZhUPZsK?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now. Is it possible to read the header state and change icon for active header?

Comment: Commenting just to say that this answer was extremely useful :)

Comment: @pkozlowski This is not working for uibootstrap version 1.2.2

Answer (score 2):

To emulate jquery-ui behavior and have the icon change based on state, you can also use the is-open attribute in accordion-group.

Here an example which works for me

```
<accordion close-others="false">

  <accordion-group is-open="section1.isOpen">
    <accordion-heading>
      <i ng-class="{true : 'icon-chevron-down', false : 'icon-chevron-right'}[!!section1.isOpen]"></i>
      <strong> SECTION 1</strong>
    </accordion-heading>
  CONTENT SECTION 1
  </accordion-group>
  <accordion-group is-open="section2.isOpen">
    <accordion-heading>
      <i ng-class="{true : 'icon-chevron-down', false : 'icon-chevron-right'}[!!section2.isOpen]"></i>
      <strong> SECTION 2</strong>
    </accordion-heading>
  CONTENT SECTION 2
  </accordion-group>

</accordion>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/CODNWD7WiBHDfYHHuK7C?p=preview