# Accordion header images as links on AngularUI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186404/accordian-header-images-in-angularui/16190861#) shows us how to add header images in AngularUI accordion. Is there a way to use that image (and only the image, not the header text) as a href to a website? Thank you.

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E4QtpTYpHkMmcZhUPZsK?p=preview) provided in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML as you normally would inside the accordion-heading element. Wrap the `i` element in anchor tags to make it a link:

```
<accordion-heading>
    Put any HTML <strong>here</strong>
    <a href="http://www.example.com"><i class="icon-book"></i></a>
</accordion-heading>
```

Comment: That was my first try and it doesn't work... See this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HerYXlquKjABa2SXTEX6?p=preview

Comment: You will probably need to modify the directive code. The default accordion template in ui-bootstrap's source code has an ng-click on the element that wraps the header contents: `<a class=\"accordion-toggle\" ng-click=\"toggleOpen()\" ...>`. As the ng-click directive will intercept all clicks, one way you can do it is to modify the directive's `toggleOpen` method to check the click event's target element. If the target was an anchor with a href, let the browser handle the event normally.

Comment: Which version are you referring to?